String with html <span> formatting not working with Javascript code
I have a flask app which I query for some database values. These values I want to format as strings with some additional text. Also I want to format these with some html <span class=""> elements so I can style them in CSS.
Here's the part where the string is formatted in flask:
today_record_data = (
            f"<span class='record_text'>Your total today: </span>" 
            f"<span class='record_value'>{total_amount_today} gram</span>"
            f"<span class='record_text'>Your total this week: </span>"
            f"<span class='record_value'>{total_amount_week} gram</span>"
        )

In my html I have a menu. When clicked the corresponding data is extracted from the database and should be displayed in an innerhtml.
Here's the html:
<nav class="highscore_menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="displayData('{{ today_record_data|safe }}', event)">Today</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div id="info-display">{{ today_record_data|safe }}</div>

Here's the Javascript:
<script>
        function displayData(data, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action
            document.getElementById('info-display').innerHTML = data;
        }
</script>

When I just format the variable today_record_data = {total_amount_today} it works. But when formatting as multiline with html tags it stops functioning. I though adding |safe would make sure it is not HTML escaped when rendered in the JavaScript function displayData.
The string is displaying correct for the initialization of the innerhtml: <div id="info-display">{{ today_record_data|safe }}</div>
The console is giving this error when the menu item is clicked:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (at VM20035 my_dumps:1:13) 

If the error is in my_dumps, it'd be worth sharing that part. Can always remove your name/username/other sensitive info if it's actual dumps.

Solved:
The problem was in a conflixt of ' and ".
I changed this: " here
# record data
today_record_data = (
    f"<span class=\"record_text\">Your total today: </span>" 
    f"<span class=\"record_value\">{total_amount_today} gram</span>"
    f"<span class=\"record_text\">Your total this week: </span>"
    f"<span class=\"record_value\">{total_amount_week} gram</span>"
)

And removed the |safe here:
<li><a href="#" onclick="displayData('{{ today_record_data }}', event)">Today</a></li>

